# AngularJS IE8 Issues

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, angularjs

I have been unable to render a list in IE8 specifically. All other browsers execute the following code as intended, however, IE8 completely ignores the function completely. Any tips, suggestions and/or solutions are greatly appreciated, Cheers.

```
alert("workflow.js"+ " this call goes off in IE8");

$scope.makeAndGetList = function(list) {
    //todo: lj: IE8 doesn't make it here
    //alert("workflow.js"+ " no IE");
    var parts = list.split('.'),
        current = $scope.workflow;

    _.each(parts, function(part, index) {
        if (current[part] == undefined) {
            current[part] = (index == parts.length - 1) ? [] : {};
        }
        current = current[part];
        //todo: lj: IE8 doesn't make it in here
        // app.appAlert("workflow.js"+ " line 19");
    });

alert("workflow.js - this functions correctly executes in IE8");
```

Here is the HTML as requested:

```
<sa-list list="makeAndGetList('areas_of_need')" edit="true" model="areas_of_need" array-mode="true">
    <sa-lookup style="multiselect" override="false" list="areas_of_need.terms" model="areas_of_need" model-key="need" label="{{locale.iprc.areas_of_strengths_and_needs.needs}}"></sa-lookup>
</sa-list>
```

Comment: How is `makeAndGetList` called? Can you show the HTML here as well?

Comment: In case you haven't seen it yet this discusses IE Compatibility: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Comment: Thanks Gloopy for the tip, unfortunately, I have read through the IE guide and created the elements as shown but it didn't solve the issue

Comment: I had an issue with potentially reserved keywords as attribute names and not being able to access them within a directive. I had an attribute in the markup named 'value' that I would try and access in the directive by doing element.value but it wouldn't work until I renamed it element.val or element.value2. Maybe try renaming the list attribute to list2 in your sa-list as a test?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is your issue (can you post a jsfiddle with your directives?), but here's a possibility. IE 8 can handle angular directives only as attributes (not elements). Luckily, it is easy to change an angular element into an attribute. E.g., for a directive "saList", where the html says `<sa-list>`, rewrite the html as `<div sa-list>` (and make sure your directive has the property `restrict: 'A'`, not `restrict: 'E'`). See an example (that works in IE 8) here: http://jsfiddle.net/dannystaten/hQn9F/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [ieshiv](http://angular-ui.github.com/) I wrote it for angular-ui project. Gives you an easy way to incorporate.

Answer (score 0):

Also try upgrading to 0.2.0 version of Angular UI Bootstrap. I was facing similar issues for "Alert" control. After upgrading it to 0.2.0 and using it as attribute resolved my issue